# How to fix mypy type Any error in sqlalchemy Table.columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, type-hinting, mypy

I'm still new to type hints. Here's the minimal code example of the error I'm getting:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

t = sa.Table("a", sa.MetaData(), sa.Column("id_", sa.Integer))
cols = t.columns
```

This raises the following error when I run mypy:

```
error: Expression type contains "Any" (has type "ReadOnlyColumnCollection[str, Column[Any]]")  [misc]
```

I'm running mypy with the following configuration turned on ([link](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-disallow-any-expr)):

```
disallow_any_expr = true
```

I've looked at the sql alchemy source code and the `.colums` method of the `Table` class does indeed have the return type that mypy states.

I don't know however how could I go about altering that to remove the Any. Would that be even the correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

If it's not source code that *you* control<sup>(a)</sup>, the easiest option is usually to drop a `# type: ignore [xxx]` at the end of the offending line.

I usually also place a comment stating *why* it's needed so that anyone looking at the code later understands since, during our PR process, we have to justify any disabling of checks for the compliance tools `mypy/pylint/bandit/isort/black`.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> We also follow this guideline if the effort to fix our legacy code is more than a certain threshold. For example, we don't want to have to refactor 10,000 lines of code to make a one-line bug fix :-) All new code (that we control) has to comply however.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the latest sqlalchemy version?
for me, when I run mypy to test your code, I find no issues:

```
f.py:5: note: Revealed type is "sqlalchemy.sql.base.ReadOnlyColumnCollection[builtins.str, sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Column[Any]]"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

when running at:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

t = sa.Table("a", sa.MetaData(), sa.Column("id_", sa.Integer))
cols = t.columns
reveal_type(cols)
```

- Mypy: 1.0.0
- sqlalchemy: 2.0.2

Comment: Apologies, forgot to add I'm running with the following config turned on `disallow_any_expr`. Will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: with the `disallow_any_expr` config, you are forced to use `# type: ignore`, because the `:property:columns` is returning `ReadOnlyColumnCollection[str, Column[Any]]` with the `Any` as a `Column` type paramenter.